# contact us page submit but email not received

Tags: email, magento2.3.3

when contact us page submit but email not received but messages display

**Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We'll respond to you very soon.**

in **debug.log** I get this error.

```
main.CRITICAL: Unable to send mail: Unknown error {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php:104, Zend\\Mail\\Transport\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Unable to send mail: Unknown error at /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Transport/Sendmail.php:305)"} []
```

in **exception.log** I get this error.

```
main.CRITICAL: Invalid header value detected {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\MailException(code: 0): Invalid header value detected at /public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Transport.php:104, Zend\\Mail\\Header\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Invalid header value detected at /public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mail/src/Header/HeaderValue.php:112)"} []
```

Comment: Have you set SMTP correct?

Comment: @VijayKhirade
 im use magentos default configuration

Comment: getting almost same error on 2.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential fix is to add encoding in vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
--- vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php.org 2019-10-07 17:16:16.946791204 +0200
+++ vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php 2019-10-07 17:16:44.243320666 +0200
@@ -402,6 +402,7 @@
             (string)$template->getSubject(),
             ENT_QUOTES
         );
+        $this->messageData['encoding'] = $mimePart->getCharset();
         $this->message = $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory->create($this->messageData);

         return $this;
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24902